# Is there something like Microsoft's TechNet or MSDN subcriptions for Apple?

Tags: macos

I would like to test software designed to run on a Mac and would need a couple of OS versions (old ones, too) and maybe other Mac software to set up my (virtual) test machines.

For the same scenario on Windows, I can use the licenses available via TechNet or MSDN subscriptions. At the [ADC Mac Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/mac/), I couldn't find any specific information as to what is available. Does an ADC membership get me downloads of software / OS's to test against? If not, what is available?

Comment: @Ian: I took a guess in the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. You can download the operating systems as well as betas (although not as early as "proper" beta testers).

Comment: Do you know if hey have OS Classic there, too, and if I may set up multiple installations? Or, even better, do you know a page where they list all this? I'm sure there is one, though I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 5):

Bear in mind that I don't believe any version of Mac OS (barring OS X Server) is licensed for use in a VM. In theory, if you want to test different versions of the OS you'll need to do either multiple installs on a single system (My first iMac came with OS 9 and OS X installed this way, not sure you could get multiple OS X versions installed on a single box) or have lots of boxes.

Comment: Are you sure about this? It seems weird to me, because I imagine it's very inefficient for testing, isn't it?

Comment: I'm sure about the licensing. Yes, it is a pain for testing.